# Android appcompat edittext input automatically changes to selected language text problem

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin, language-translation

Hi Every One I am facing rare problem in an android app currently I am working on. Whenever my app has changed to different language except from english.EditText input value  and TextView in my app automatically changes strings according to selected language though these strings are not from Strings.xml files. I could not find the cause for this problem. I am expecting any kind of help to get rid of this scenario. Thank you in advance

Comment: add screenshot with you gradle config and project tree

Comment: android:configChanges="locale"
Place the line in activity tag in Manifest file
It will disable the effect of phone language changes to your app